# Dynamic Role Based Access Control per Page and per Input field of a Page

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

Im having a hard time to create an RBAC Model in PHP that goes down to a Page restriction then field restriction.
Ive already Made a RBAC for Pages only. My model is something like this.

User -> Role -> Module(page) -> Action -> Permission

But is it possible to create rights and permission down to an input field of a page?

Something Like this?

User -> Role -> Module -> Page -> Field -> Permission.

On Page Product

User A can see Product Cost Field and Product Price Field.

But

User B can only see Product Price Field. on the Product page.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible. What exactly is your question? How to model this?

Comment: Yeah how to model it, or perhaps an example system similar to this? 
The requirement was to do it on a query only, without using any If statement in PHP.

Comment: What result do you want from the query, then?

Comment: Im not really sure how can it be done without using If statement in PHP.
Since the query would return True or False to an access right?

Comment: Yes, you will likely have to have a conditional somewhere to check the result of the query. Sharing your current implementation(for the page-based version) would be a good starting point to explain how a field-based version would differ. Ultimately, I think you'd want a query when viewing a page to provide a list of acceptable fields and a query when updating a field that checks that the user has access for the requested field(s). Is the requirement to not use a literal `if` statement, or conditionals in general? If the former, loops, ternary operators, etc. could be used. A conditional is req

Comment: Literally no IF statements, they want that the RBAC can be so dynamic that even without a programmer it can be set up. Im currently losing my mind.

Comment: They want to set up new users/roles or new fields dynamically? If the former, that certainly makes sense. For the latter, I'd have to know more about your overall architecture to comment, but I suspect is an expensive change. Sometimes you'll have to deal with requirements that don't make sense. If they aren't impossible(this isn't), you can work around them. Sometimes requirements are made without adequate technical understanding and can be negotiated with sufficient explanation, though. It sounds like there may be a disconnect between you and the issuer of the requirement.

Comment: The issuer is my Supervisor he codes, he says its possible and you only need a good DB Structure, but i dont know how is it possible. The flow would be set up a new user then assign role. based on the role. the input fields would be filtered.